# remove all user wordpress capabilities from a specific user

Tags: php, wordpress

We want to remove specific user capability from a user, so we use that line of code below and it works for a specific capability:

```
$user->remove_cap( 'edit_pages');
```

but what if we want to delete all user capabilities of that specific user ?, we dont need to list all the capabilities because the line of code below doesn't work

```
$user->remove_cap( 'edit_pages', 'publish_products');
```

So is there is a way to delete all the capabilities with a line of code to remove all the capabilities instead of removing a specific capability ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is get a list of all the capabilities said user has, then loop through them and remove each one like so:

```php
$caps = $user->allcaps;

foreach($caps as $cap) {
    $user->remove_cap($cap);
}
```

I believe this should work, if it doesn't or you have any clarifications you'd like me to make please let me know.

Source for [All Capabilities (allcaps)](https://isabelcastillo.com/list-capabilities-current-user-wordpress)

Comment: Sorry it did not work .. didn't remove any capability this way

Comment: Can you post the result of doing `print_r($user);` in your question please, because this may help us find the property which contains all of the capabilities of said user, which we can then apply my solution above to.

Comment: can you help us even to remove the capabilities by listing them all, this works fine and remove the capability: `$user->remove_cap( 'publish_products');` .. while when we list more than 1 capability it doesn't work and did not remove the capabilities:  `$user->remove_cap( 'edit_pages', 'publish_products');` .. can you help us with a way to list all the capabilities ?

Comment: remove_cap takes one parameter which is the name of the capability, so adding 2 parameters wouldn't work.

Comment: so how can we remove more than 1 capability ?

Comment: You have to write `$user->remove_cap("capability");` for each capability you are trying to remove

Comment: And why it can not work with a foreach loop as you mentioned above ?

Answer (score 1):

The [WP_User::remove_all_caps()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/remove_all_caps/) method does just that:

```php
//Remove all of the capabilities of the user.
$user->remove_all_caps( );
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on an earlier answer, you could loop through and remove them, but you'll need the name of the capability, not the value.

```
foreach($user->allcaps as $key=>$value) {
    $user->remove_cap($key);
}
```

I haven't tested this a lot, but simply setting the array of capabilities to an empty array should do it too.

```
$user->allcaps = array();
```